# CaseWhen in spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.4

I'd like to understand how to use the `CaseWhen` expressions with the new `DataFrame` api.

I can't see any reference to it in the documentation, and the only place I saw it was in the code:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.4.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/predicates.scala#L397

I'd like to be able to write something like this:

```
val col = CaseWhen(Seq(
    $"a" === lit(1), lit(10),
    $"a" === lit(2), lit(15),
    ...
    lit(20)
))
```

but this code won't compile because the `Seq` is of type `Column` and not `Expression`

What is the proper way to use `CaseWhen`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, I don't know whether `CaseWhen` is intended to be used as a user facing API. Instead you should use the `when` and `otherwise` method of the `Column` type. With those methods you can construct a `CaseWhen` column.

```scala
val column: Column = //some column

val result: Column = column.
  when($"a" === functions.lit(1), 10).
  when($"a" === functions.lit(2), 15).
  otherwise(20)
```

Comment: You might be right, although it's not `private[slq]` nor marked as `@DeveloperApi`.
And I can't do  `column.expr` since `expr` is `protected`

Comment: You're right. I missed that `expr` is protected. But I found another solution. I updated the answer. I hope this works now.